# My webpage won't stay at full screen on different screen size despite using viewport etc

Tags: html, css

For my webpage I am tried to make it a one page website that fits all screen without scrolling, but I had white spaces in between my section and nav and footer so I added this box-sizing code:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

It works for my desktop screen and s10 galaxy phone, but when I check my laptop the footer was stuck at something like "bottom: 10px" but when I check the css using inspect, it shows the css for the footer is at bottom: 0; You can view this bug via the snippet and if the using inspect and change width to >1000px. In my opinion it might have to do with the @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) which i set it to 1000px, If I change the height of section, class main, it will move the footer into the correct position but thats not the case for the different screen size monitors.

If I remove the box-sizing, the white spaces (not padding or margin) is above my section tag which I do not want but the footer is at bottom: 0px. So I am 100% confused. is there something wrong with my css or am I missing something that would be a fix all solution. Any help would be great! Thank you for the help in advance!

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 91.8%;
  padding: 10% 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.headerNav {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 100;
  max-width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.homePG {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.headerLogin {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 5px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.navIcon {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: blue;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

#mobile-navLinks {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #mobile-navLinks {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .main {
    height: 91.5%;
  }
  .homePGh1 {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .homePGpara {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .headerLogin {
    display: none;
  }
  .navIcon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="headerNav">
    <nav>
      <a href="/index.html" class="homePG">HOME</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="headerLogin">
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navIcon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mobileNavs()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </nav>
    <div id="mobile-navLinks">
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
      <a href="/index.html" class="">HOME</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="main">
    <div>
      <h1 class="homePGh1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </h1>
      <p class="homePGpara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p class="homePGpara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Nunc sed
        blandit libero volutpat. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. </p>
      <p class="homePGpara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Nunc sed
        blandit libero volutpat. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar.</p>

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    © 2020 
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use 100vh and calc

Comment: @frankfurt it doesn't work for mobile, but works perfectly for desktop/laptops is there a workaround for mobile devices.